# Numpy Dot Product - Shape Error with identical shape

Tags: python, numpy

Have been completely stuck on a rather silly issue: I'm trying to compute the dot product of some attributes between objects, but keep getting a Value Error - Shape Mismatch - but the shapes are identical (2,1) and (2,1), since the arrays are just attributes of different instances of the same class:

```
class MyClass(Object):
      def __init__(self, a,b, x,y):
          self.prop_1 = np.array((a,b))
          self.prop_2 = np.array((x,y))
```

where all a, b, x, and y are scalars. then further down I'm trying

```
def MyFunction(Obj1, Obj2):
    results = np.dot(Obj1.prop_1 - Obj2.prop_1, Obj2.prop_2 - Obj2.prop_3)
```

which keeps throwing the Value Error

```
ValueError: shapes (2,1) and (2,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)
```

Mathematically, this dot product should be fine - but the final bit of the error message kind of suggests I have to transpose one of the arrays. I'd be very thankful for a short explanation of the numpy shape interpretation to avoid this kind of error!

EDIT:

Think I misphrased this a bit. When I initiate my objects via (case a)

```
a,b = np.random.rand(2)
x,y = np.random.rand(2)
MyClass(a, b, x, y)
```

Everything works like a charm. If instead however I initiate as (case b)

```
a = np.random.rand(1)
b = np.random.rand(1)
x = np.random.rand(1)
y = np.random.rand(1)
MyClass(a, b, x, y)
```

the dot product later on fails to work because of the shape mismatch.

I have noticed that in case b, each individual value is of shape `(1,)`  and it's clear to me that combining two of these will result in shape `(2,1)` instead of shape `()` in case a - but why do these two ways of declaring a variable result in different shapes?

As you can tell I'm relatively new to Python and thought this was just a neat way to perform multiple assignments - turns out there is some further reasoning behind it, and i'd be interested to hear about that.

Comment: should it be `np.dot(a.T, b)` ? `np.dot(a.ravel(), b.ravel())` would also work.

Comment: How are you creating the instance of `MyClass` i.e. what are the values of `a`, `b` etc? Also please fix the typo in `innit` and where are all the `self` arguments? If `a` and `b` were scalars, then `self.prop_1` would have a shape of `(2,)` and you wouldn't have a problem.

Comment: For 1d arrays. `dot` does the inner, scalar product.  For 2d (which you have) it does matrix product - remember the manual row with columns method?

Comment: @Dan all arguments are scalars - shape `1,` but once I combine them I end up with the shape mentioned in the question.

Comment: @LoschmidtsSchnitzel please make a reproducible example `(np.array((1, 2)) - np.array((3, 4))).shape` returns `(2,)`, so where ever your code is converting this to a `(2, 1)` is not shown in your question. Please add the code where you call `MyFunction` and the code where you create the two objects you are passing to it.

Comment: @Dan included one now - i think the reason for my flip from 1D to 2D might lie in my usage of ```np.random.rand```

Comment: @LoschmidtsSchnitzel yes now the problem becomes clear. `np.random.random` creates numpy arrays. When you tried to initiate your array with other arrays you made an array of arrays. Numpy logically assumed you wanted to make a 2D array, otherwise you'd have passed in simple floats. When you went `a, b = np.random.random(2)` you took advantage of unpacking to assign each element of the sequence (the array in this case) to it's own variable. This results in `a` and `b` being simple floats. Later when you try `np.array((a, b))`, since you've passed in floats, numpy will you a 1D array.

Comment: Thanks, now i get it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Part 1**

The issue is that your arrays are full-blown 2-D matrices, not 1D "vectors" in the sense that [`np.dot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) understands it. To get your multiplication working, you need to either (a) convert your vectors to vectors:

```
np.dot(a.reshape(-1), b.reshape(-1))
```

(b) set up the matrix multiplication so that the dimensions work. Remember that the dot product of two Nx1 matrices is A<sup>T</sup>B:

```
np.dot(a.T, b)
```

or (c), use [np.einsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to explicitly set the dimension of the sum:

```
np.einsum('ij,ij->j', a, b).item()
```

For all of the examples using `dot`, you can use [`np.matmul`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) (or equivalently the `@` operator), or [`np.tensordot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html), because you have 2D arrays.

In general, keep the following rules in mind when working with `dot`. Table cells are `einsum` subscripts

```
                                      A
      |         1D        |          2D         |                ND             |
   ---+-------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------+
   1D | i,i->             | ij,j->i             | a...yz,z->a...y               |
   ---+-------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------+
B  2D | i,ij->j           | ij,jk->ik           | a...xy,yz->a...xz             |
   ---+-------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------+
   ND | y,a...xyz->a...xz | ay,b...xyz->ab...xz | a...mxy,n...wyz->a...mxn...wz |
   ---+-------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------+
```

Basically, `dot` follows normal rules for matrix multiplication along the last two dimensions, but the leading dimensions are always combined. If you want the leading dimensions to be broadcast together for arrays > 2D (i.e., multiplying corresponding elements in a stack of matrices, rather all possible combinations), use `matmul` or `@` instead.

**Part 2**

When you initialize the inputs as `a, b = np.random.rand(2)`, you are unpacking the two elements of the array into scalars:

```
>>> a, b = np.random.rand(2)
>>> a
0.595823752387523
>>> type(a)
numpy.float64
>>> a.shape
()
```

Note that the type is not `numpy.ndarray` in this case. However, when you do `a = np.random.rand(1)`, the result is a 1D array of one element:

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(1)a
>>> a
array([0.21983553])
>>> type(a)
numpy.ndarray
>>> a.shape
(1,)
```

When you create a numpy array from numpy arrays, the result is a 2D array:

```
>>> np.array([1, 2]).shape
(2,)
>>> np.array([np.array([1]), np.array([2])]).shape
(2, 1)
```

Going forward, you have two options. You can either be more careful with your inputs, or you can sanitize the array after you've created it.

You can expand the arrays that you feed in:

```
ab = np.random.rand(2)
xy = np.random.rand(2)
MyClass(*ab, *xy)
```

Or you can just flatten/ravel your arrays once you've created them:

```
def __init__(self, a, b, x, y):
     self.prop_1 = np.array([a, b]).ravel()
     self.prop_2 = np.array([x, y]).ravel()
```

You can use `....reshape(-1)` instead of `...ravel()`.

Comment: (d) use `np.tensordot(a, b, axes=(0,0))`

Comment: thanks for the answer. In what way tho would I have to create the property arrays to be a simple 1D vector? For context, the properties are spatial position and velocity of particles so it'd feel natural to have them as standard 1D vectors.

Comment: @LoschmidtsSchnitzel. Just don't add the second dimension? The statement `np.array((a,b))` produces a 1D array already. I'm not sure what you did to get 2D, but it wasn't that.

Comment: Are you using `MyClass(1,2)` or `MyClass([1],[2])`?

Comment: @Feodoran. Added a reference

Comment: @LoschmidtsSchnitzel. I've added an update to answer your question based on your update

Comment: @hpaulj. Addressed your question

Comment: Thanks, great answer!